# How to change standard fields names in logback LogstashSocketAppender?

Tags: logback, logstash-logback-encoder

In my Spring backend: standard log fields names are: **"message"** and **"level"** and logback.xml file works great:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="5 seconds">
    <property resource="application.properties"/>
    <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] <%-5level> [Backend] <%thread> &msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

**Question:**
How to change standard log field names using **LogstashSocketAppender** from "**message**" to "**log-message**"?

I already try add this appender:

```
<appender name="stash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashSocketAppender">
    <host>localhost</host>
    <port>6002</port>
    <customFields>
        {
        "timestamp":"%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}",
        "component": "Backend",
        "log-message": "%msg",
        "log-level": "%-5level"
        }</customFields>
</appender>
```

but my outpust looks like this:

```
{
"message":"correct log message here"
"log-message":"%msg" <--- BAD VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I already done this by use pattern:

```
<appender name="stash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashSocketAppender">
    <host>${logstash.host}</host>
    <port>${logstash.port}</port>
    <provider class="net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.LoggingEventPatternJsonProvider">
        <pattern>
            {
            "log-message": "%msg",
            "component": "Backend",
            "timestamp": "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}",
            "log-level": "%-5level",
            "thread-id": "%thread"
            }
        </pattern>
    </provider>
</appender>
```

Edit: Ofcourse then you must create `grok > match` filter in your logstash to listen on this pattern.